# How to access destination service which is behind RabbitMQ using S4 Cloud SDK Connectivity

Tags: java, jwt, s4sdk, sap-cloud-sdk

We are using S4SDK to access destination service. it needs to work in multi-tenancy env. Normally if the app is a frontend app, the request context is triggered by user request. Accessing destination service with multi-tenancy is doable with approuter and XUAA. 
In our case, our application is behind RabbitMQ which is not trigger by a user request (e.g. REST API call). Currently we are using the class com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationAccessor from cloud SDK. we can retrieve a tenant id out of message (RabbitMQ/AMQP). The issue is that we cannot find a way to inject the tenant id or clone a JWT token into DestinationAccessor from S4SDK. We look for a way/guidance of how to achieve that. We expect this exchange/clone token is provided by the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [JwtBasedRequestContextExecutor](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/08/02/sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-version-2.2.0-is-available/) for this purpose.

```
new JwtBasedRequestContextExecutor()
    .withJwt(encodedJwt)
    .execute(() -> {
        // code using the SAP Cloud SDK
    });
```